# Link with UNC path is broken after copying cells from Excel 2010 to Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-word-2010, unc

I am trying to copy an Excel table to Word in Office 2010. Basically, if the hyperlinks are pointing to my local hard drive, there are no problem at all. However, if the hyperlink is pointing to a UNC path or network location, after copying the table to Word, all links path are broken.

The file name is still there, but the path becomes C:\Users\$MyUserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.MSO\@FileName

The original UNC path I linked in Excel is the full path (\server\dir1\dir2\file.ext), not a mapped network drive.

Did I missed some Office 2010 fix or update? Our company controls the update policy of our computers, so we do not always get the latest update from windows update.

Thanks in advance.